# Should I use pgreloaded? Or subversion of pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using pygame with python 2.6 right now, But I want to use python 3.1.1 instead. The normal pygame only works with 2.x, but the subversion ones work with 3.x I think. But what about pgreloaded? Is that useable yet? The normal pygame actually works with 3.1 too, but not for os x (at least there isn't a download). Does anyone actually use pgreloaded or subversion pygames? So anyway, should I use pygame subversion, pgreloaded, or stick with the current pygame? I don't really care about being compatible with other things or distribution.

Thanks!

EDIT: Ok, I got rid of python 2.6, installed 3.1, used svn command to get pygame, tried running python3 setup.py, didn't work, changed raw_input in setup.py to input(), worked, now my pygames (that were so simple that they work the same under 2.6 and 3.1) run with python 3.1. :) I didn't get pgreloaded because there's no documentation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick with Python 2.6.

Comment: No one answered, so I let everyone know What I decided.

Comment: From the FAQ (stackoverflow.com/faq): "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: haha, great answer. yeah it's very tempting as a dev to jump onto new things. but often you just gotta hang back with the crowd. better tools, better docs, better performance. i dabbled in 3.1 for a few months, and i'm now back on 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

pgreloaded has documentation - there is even an own package at http://code.google.com/p/pygame/downloads/list.

Answer (score 1):

I think JD's link to pgreloaded doc is out of date, try this one:
http://wiki.pgreloaded.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Or consider using Pyglet (http://pyglet.org/), which is a thin wrapper around openGL, esp. made for games.  It works pretty well, documentation is reasonable, but it of course lacks the massive userbase that Pygame has.  It is more mature than PGreloaded imho.